# appium how to select a photo from Gallery

Tags: java, android, gallery, appium

I'm *testing an android application* that has a functionality to set a *photo from the gallery of the phone as an avatar*. My devices runs on **API LEVEL 4.2.2**, I'm using Appium 1.2.4.1. and coding using Java. I was wondering how can I access a *specific photo*. The first screen shows all the *root folders* where photos are (for example 100ANDRO) and after clicking this i can access the photos. The Inspector Window shows no element that can be selected to navigate to the photos. Here is what i see from the Inspector:

[image: image description here]

Any ideas how i can actually access the photo and select it? Thanks!!!

Comment: with the inspector you can gather the xpath to use, but that's brittle, as it makes your test depend on a specific version of the application.

Comment: (although, from the looks of it, the actual content is not in the tree.)

Answer (score -2):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Comment: A short explanation of what you're doing here would be helpful. :-)

Comment: As i said above I'm trying to run a test using appium (so selenium classes) in Eclipse. So i think i cant use Android classes like Intent etc.

Comment: that does not answer the question

Answer (score -2):

You can use Intent to access the Gallery images -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

and handle the callback by -

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
     */
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            // just some safety built in 
            if( uri == null ) {
                // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                return null;
            }
            // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
            // this will only work for images selected from gallery
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if( cursor != null ){
                int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            // this is our fallback here
            return uri.getPath();
    }
```

I think this will help you :)

Comment: I'm trying to run a test using appium (so selenium classes) in Eclipse. So i think i cant use Android classes like Intent etc.

Comment: that does not answer the question